# ZSH file completions from 2 path

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, zsh-completion

I have 2 folders that contains folders

```
/me/foo/: 
  a/
  b/
  c/

/me/bar/:
  c/
  d/
  e/
```

I want to create completion function for command `baz` so that

`$ baz [tab]`

gives completion arguments as follow

```
a b c d e
```

notice the duplicate `c` written only once and it doesn't include the trailing slash.

I know how to do completion with `_files` but that only gives me file from single directory.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I found this is working for me

```
local services
services=$(ls -d /me/foo/*/ /me/bar/*/ | xargs basename| uniq)
_alternative "dirs:some directories:($services)"
```

Comment: This does not look like `services` would contain each name only once. It also depends on the implementation of `basename`, not all of which allow multiple arguments by default. I would suggest using `local -U services=((foo|bar)/*(/:t))`. With `-U` an array only keeps the first occurrence of identical values. `(foo|bar)/*` matches any child of the directories `foo` and `bar`. The qualifier `(/)` limits this to only directories and `(:t)` removes all leading path components aka `basename`. It also removes the need for any external command.

Comment: Hmm i get a bad pattern when trying `local -U services((foo|bar)/*(/:t)` and `echo $service` the error was `a.zsh:1: bad pattern: services((foo|bar)/*(/:t)\necho \n` where can I find the documentation of that pattern?

Comment: It looks like the `=` is missing. But I get the the same error message (even with the `=`) when trying to run this on a older `zsh` with version 5.0.6. I currently use 5.2. It seems that the ability to typeset and assign arrays in a single command [was added in 5.1](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/releases.html). Separating it in `local -U services` and `services=(…)` should work. As for documentation: have a look at the section on [Filename Generation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation) in the ZSH manual.